# Unexpected value in TYPE field in CallLog.Calls

Tags: android, api, constants, voice

I'm using a data set of **Call Logs** from Android phones and have started seeing unexpected values in the TYPE field, which indicates details about the direction of calls (Eg. Incoming, Outgoing, Missed, VoiceMail)

The documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#TYPE) suggests values should be limited to 1-7. Since mid July, I have a few scattered values of 8, 9, 10, 1000, 1001, and 1002. I can't find any references to those values in either the developer documentation or general searches.

Has anyone seen these (or other) unexpected values before? Any guidance on how to determine if their actual direction?

Many thanks to this community.

Comment: what device are you trying this on? OEM generally override a lot of default behaviour.

Comment: LG K8 (android v6 at install) giving 8, 9,10
Alcatel One Touch (v5? hard to say) and some kind of ZTE (v7 at install) giving 1000, 1001, 1002.

All of these are apearing in addition to the expected values, if that matters.

Comment: i think it has something to do with bitmasking of other types like video etc. let me check it once.